# How can i make branch on all not integer variables at each node?

Tags: cplex

At each node, I would like to make branch on all variables which their values are not integers. After that i would like to print the value of objective at each branch. I wrote this code in C++ but I got error 1006.

```
ILOBRANCHCALLBACK1(callback1, IloNumVarArray, vars)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vars.getSize(); ++i)
      {
        if (getValue(vars[i]) > 0 && getValue(vars[i]) < 1)
        {
        int xidown = IloFloor(getValue(vars[i]));
        int xiup   = IloFloor(getValue(vars[i])) + 1;
        makeBranch(vars[i], xidown, IloCplex::BranchDown, getObjValue());
        makeBranch(vars[i], xiup, IloCplex::BranchUp, getObjValue());
        cout << "objvalueDown_" << vars[i] << "," << getObjValue() << endl;
        cout << "objvalueUp_"   << vars[i] << "," << getObjValue() << endl;
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create more than two branches at a node, that is why you get this error.

Moreover, the newly created nodes are not evaluated immediately, they are just put onto the node queue. So you cannot query the objective values of the newly created nodes just then.

In case you are trying to do something like strong branching then please search the reference manual for "strong branching". There are dedicated functions for this.

Comment: Thank you dear Daniel. You’re right. i would like to compute strong branching for all fractional variables at each node but according the data I retrieved from Cplex with concert C++, I can just compute strong branching for the variable is selected for branching. Now according to your answer I don’t know how to compute for other fractional variables at each node.

Comment: In C++ the IloCplex class has getStrongBranch() member functions. In order to use this you have to the following: Create a new `IloModel` instance and add the `IloModel` instance currently under optimization to this. Then add constraints to the new `IloModel` instance that reflect the local bounds at the current node. Finally, create a new `IloCplex` instance, extract the new `IloModel` instance to it and call `getStrongBranch()`. As you can see, this is a bit complicated. Maybe it is easier to configure CPLEX to do full strong branching?